# ModSim -Package - Issues in installation Issue on MacBookPro (2014)

Tags: python, installation, pip, package, simulation

I receive an issue in the installation of Modsim package:

`pip install modsim` is not working on my MacBookPro -2014

**Software Version:** macOS 10.15.6 (19G2021)

**Python Version:**
Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug 13 2019, 15:17:50)
[Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin

Can you please help me in the setup of the modsim package for my MacBook?

Comment: It would really be useful if you included the error message that you got when trying to run `pip install modsim`. Just stating "is not working" does not explain much!

Answer (score 0):

I tried pip install modsim in anaconda on Windows and it didn't work either. I still have errors in my own code using modsim so I cannot confirm if modsim is working but the installation of the package below worked:

```
    pip install modsimpy
```

Try looking in here: https://pypi.org/project/modsimpy/

Edit: My code is functioning now. Referring to the link with some minor changes,
I proceeded after the "modsimpy" install to do:

```
    conda install jupyterlab pandas seaborn sympy beautifulsoup4 lxml html5lib pytables

    pip install pint
```